# Draw "snake" like count down timer in android application

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to draw a count down timer in android that looks a little like a growing "snake" (from the Nokia game in the 90s).  I can manage the count down timer side of the code but have no idea where to start with drawing the thin line around the outside of the screen that grows as the time counts down.

I did wonder about making lots of little imageviews and then un-hiding them as the count down happened but that seems a really bad way of achieving what I want.

Sorry for the vague question, but I have no idea where to start at all with this and need a steer in the right direction.

Thanks;

Andy

Comment: Yes, many [many] tiny image views would be quite inefficient! Why not just [handle the Canvas drawing](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) manually?

Comment: Thanks for the steer.  I thought there must be a good way of getting the snake.  I am new to Java and have never looked at custom drawing effects.  I am starting to read up now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone finds this thread via google/searching here is the code I went for:

```
 private class CustomView extends View {
         public CustomView(Context context) {
               super(context);
           }
         @Override
           protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
               super.onDraw(canvas);
               if (direction==120){
                   direction=0;
               }
               Paint green = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
               green.setColor(Color.GREEN);
               green.setStrokeWidth(3);
               Paint red = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
               red.setColor(Color.RED);
               red.setStrokeWidth(4);
               Paint thickgreen = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
               thickgreen.setColor(Color.GREEN);
               thickgreen.setStrokeWidth(20);
               // thickgreen.setShadowLayer(12, 15, 15, Color.BLUE);
               Paint thickred = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
               thickred.setColor(Color.RED);
               thickred.setStrokeWidth(20);
               //thin bar
               canvas.drawLine(barxstart, barystart, barxstop, barystop, thickgreen);
               if (direction <60  && barxstop<canvas.getWidth()) {
                    barxstop=barxstop+1; //move 5 pixels right
                    barxstart=barxstart+1; //move 5 to the right 
                }
              else{
                    canvas.drawLine(barxstart, barystart, barxstop, barystop, thickred);
                    barxstop=barxstop-1; //move 5 pixels left
                    barxstart=barxstart-1; //move 5 to the left 
                }
            //  canvas.drawBitmap(bar, barxstart, barystart, green);
                direction++;

                //mainbar
            canvas.drawLine(mainbarxstart, mainbarystart, mainbarxstop, mainbarystop, thickgreen);
            if (maindirection==1) {
              canvas.drawLine(mainbarxstart, mainbarystart, mainbarxstop, mainbarystop, thickred);
                }
            if (brainstormlate==1){
            //do something
            }
            invalidate();
            }//end ondraw canvas
        }//end custom view
```

Basic, and probably not the prettiest of things but it does work nicely for my application.